# How to talk to OpenData API Endpoint without using sodaclient in mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, socrata

How can I talk to an OpenData API Endpoint (private dataset) in an MVC application without using sodaclient? I have an apptoken and credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify, it's a private dataset, correct?

You'll need to make a RESTful HTTP call from your ASP.NET code, and include your application token as the `X-App-Token` header and provide HTTP Basic authentication with your user credentials.

Here's some helpful documentation:

- [How to make REST calls from ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)
- [SODA Basics](http://dev.socrata.com/consumers/getting-started.html)
- [SODA Authentication](http://dev.socrata.com/docs/authentication.html)
- [SODA App Tokens](http://dev.socrata.com/docs/app-tokens.html)

SoQL is pretty straightforward, so you'll just need to construct the right SoQL query for your dataset and pass that in your `GetAsync` call. I am not a ASP.NET programmer, but I think it'd look something like this.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://data.government.gov/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    // Also add X-App-Token and authentication headers here

    // New code:
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("resource/644b-gaut.json?$where=date > '2014-12-01'");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Adding in the authentication and X-App-Token headers are left as an exercise to the reader.